# Lighttpd proxy tomcat path

Tags: lighttpd

My tomcat serves 2 sites

```
ROOT -> Main-site
/mobile -> dedicated mobile website
```

I've configured lighttpd to serve as a proxy

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "www.my-site.at" {
        proxy.server = ( "" => (
                        ( "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                          "port" => 8080
                        )
                ))
}
```

How can I tell lighttpd to use http://127.0.0.1:8080/mobile for m.my-site.at? Or do I have to configure a second tomcat and deploy the mobile site under ROOT?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use [`url.rewrite-once`](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite) to prefix all requests on `m.my-site.at` with `/mobile`:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "m.my-site.at" {
    url.rewrite-once = ( ".*" => "/mobile$0" )
    proxy.server = (...)
}
```

You might have to load `mod_rewrite` before `mod_proxy` to get this working.

The problem with rewrites like this is that the backend now sees a path that doesn't match the browsers view. The backend might try to emit paths prefixed with `/mobile` or do otherwise confusing stuff with relative paths. Some proxies might try to fix these paths in responses, but lighttpd does not (and you'll never catch all of them).

The real solution is to make the backend understand vhosts - i.e. handle requests different based on the hostname. If the backend cannot do that, you might want to run multiple instances, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell lighttpd to use http://127.0.0.1:8080/mobile for m.my-site.at?

Use lighttpd.conf `proxy.header` with `"map-urlpath"` to add the `/mobile`

See [lighttpd mod_proxy](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModProxy)

As an alternative to [lighttpd mod_proxy](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModProxy), you can use [lighttpd mod_ajp13](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModAJP13) since lighttpd 1.4.59 to use the Apache jserv protocol to reach your Tomcat server.